# SBT: How to change the behavior of a task in the scope of another task which is in the scope of yet another task?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have defined a custom task like this:

```
myCustomTask := {
  val file = assembly.value
  println(file)
}
```

When I run `myCustomTask` in sbt, it will trigger `assembly`, and `assembly` will trigger `test`.

Is there a way for me to disable `test` only when `assembly` is triggered in `myCustomTask`? In other words, if I run `assembly` directly in sbt console, the `test` should still be triggered.

If I use `test in assembly := {}`, it will skip all the `test` no matter how `assembly` is called, which is not I want. On the other hand, `test in myCustomTask := {}` seems to have no effect at all.